# String to timestamp in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, timestamp

Is there any way to convert string to UNIX timestamp in MySQL?

For example, I have the string `2011-12-21 02:20pm` which needs to be in Unix timestamp format.

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp

Answer (score 70, accepted):

`UNIX_TIMESTAMP()` does the trick:

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2011-12-21 14:20:00');
```

However, the `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()` function only takes a standard MySQL formatted date. If you want to use the AM/PM notation, you will need to use [`STR_TO_DATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) first like this:

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(
    STR_TO_DATE('2011-12-21 02:20pm', '%Y-%m-%d %h:%i%p')
);
```

Answer (score 36):

Though @a'r has already given the correct answer, still something I would like to add here is that the two params **STR_TO_DATE()** function, 'date string' format and 'date format' string, should have matching placement of '-' and ':'.

For example following 4 queries return exact same result ***2014-05-28 11:30:10***

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE('2014-05-28 11:30:10','%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s');

SELECT STR_TO_DATE('20140528 11:30:10','%Y%m%d %H:%i:%s');

SELECT STR_TO_DATE('2014-05-28 113010','%Y-%m-%d %H%i%s') ;

SELECT STR_TO_DATE('20140528 113010','%Y%m%d %H%i%s');
```

**Note:** the 2 params to **STR_TO_DATE()** function in each query has matching placement for '-' and ':'

Comment: Thank you so much it was needed.