# SQL: Convert date (26.11.17) to timestamp (1516184035)

Tags: mysql, sql

Is there any way to convert a normal european date to a timestamp-value in mySQL?

I have a mysql database with a column date (varchar(64)) containing dates in european format like 01.12.15. For this I need a update-sql-query that converts all lines into timestamps.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Which DBMS do you use?

Comment: PHPmyAdmin is available.

Comment: So, MySQL then? Or is it one of the other variants? Tag it.

Comment: So you are looking for a solution in mysql?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [String to timestamp in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8587177/string-to-timestamp-in-mysql)

Comment: Yes, it is a mysql db.

Answer (score 3):

Use `STR_TO_DATE` to convert your date string `26.11.17` to a bona fide date.  Then call `UNIX_TIMESTAMP` on that date to get the UNIX timestamp.

```
SELECT
    UNIX_TIMESTAMP(STR_TO_DATE('26.11.17', '%d.%m.%y')) AS output
FROM dual;

1511650800
```

### Demo

Comment: Thanks - but how can I use this for 200 rows?

Comment: Just replace `26.11.17` with the column name.

Comment: I've selected the table, executed  your code: #1054 - Unknown column 'date' in 'field list'

Comment: Then you don't have a column called `date`.  You should have posted your table structure in the question.

Comment: The column is called date. Structure is id, tstamp, source, parent, date, name email...

Comment: NO! Edit your question.

Comment: I'm close to voting to close the question.  Don't comment here anymore.  Update your question and show table structure with sample data.

Comment: Question edited. When adding date into '-signs, the output is "NULL". Maybe the problem is that "date" is varchar(64), not timestamp?

Comment: My answer assumes that `date` is text (i.e. varchar).  There must be a problem with your data/setup, as my query is working in the demo.

Comment: Ok, I think I'm close to it. Your code gives an output. How can I write it into the column instead of the date? Thanks so far!

Comment: _Please_ update your question and show us the query you want to run, and the output you expect.

Comment: Ok, with _that_ new information in mind, I've updated the question to figure out what I really need. Sorry for beeing not precise enough.

Comment: @Dublay You should open a new question.  This question has already be answered.  Stack Overflow is not a blog where the question keeps changing.